# Ember.js: Where to put common properties?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ive heard about, that controlers gonna get deprecated some day. So im trying to just use components for everything.

But if you'r going to use some calculated properties all over the whole application, where would you implement it?

In general, I would use an application-controller and put in in there.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think services are what you are looking for.

Have a look at the following:

http://www.hutchinson.io/ember-services-and-dependency-injection/

Here's how I use a service to store application configuration (user permissions/roles, defaults, etc.):

**/app/services/configuration.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    roles: ['Administrator', 'Manager', 'User', 'View-only'],
    // ...
});
```

**/app/initializers/configuration-service.js**

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
    application.inject('route', 'configuration', 'service:configuration');
    application.inject('controller', 'configuration', 'service:configuration');
}

export default {
    name: 'configuration-service',
    initialize: initialize
};
```

Which I then access in controllers and routes like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    allRoles: function() {
        return this.configuration.roles;
}).property();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to extend `Ember.Service` (which itself is extended from `Ember.Object`)? See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Service.html

Comment: Yeah that sounds good, but with services, you cant pass arguments for specific use cases when called over the controller in the template

Comment: @MarcM What do you mean? Service properties can be declared as methods that will take parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You would build up a service and inject it everywhere necessary.

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/services-a-rumination-on-introducing-a-new-role-into-the-ember-programming-model/4947

Unless you are saying you've got common computed properties that need to decorate multiple different models, in that case you would use a mixin.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html